# How to redirect network traffic to a tcp/udp connection in golang

Tags: go, proxy, vpn, iptables, netlink

So I've seen projects like trojan-go,v2ray-go
They are making their own proxy protocols in user space level. I am trying to do the same thing but I don't know how to redirect network traffic from clients to proxy server.

Basically I don't understand how those tools (or any tool) can redirect internet traffic of the device to a certain server, so when the packets are going to the internet they go to the proxy server first instead of their destination ip address.

How can I do it in golang without dealing with netlink and Iptables?
I know apps like wireguard do this by dealing with layer 3-4 stuff using netlink API but I need to know how apps do it without adding a new network interface.

Comment: "How can I do it in golang without dealing with netlink and Iptables?" You can't. You have to convince the OS to re-route some or all traffic. To do that you have to use the facilities provided by the OS.

Comment: Do note that Go packages that wrap netlink exist, though. So you can certainly write a Go problem that sets this stuff up, but it will still call kernel APIs.